# How to define simpleType globally in JaxB

Tags: jaxb, simpletype

I have a simpleType defined in one namespace.

I will use this simpleType in another namespace. So far ok. But JaxB generate the simpleType in every package with use it. I expected and need only one global simpleType definition.

Example:
common.xsd (here is me simpleType) -> package.common.MyEnum
account.xsd -> package.account.SomeMeComplexType + package.account.MyEnum

I would like:
common.xsd -> package.common.MyEnum
account.xsd -> package.account.SomeMeComplexType + reference to package.common.MyEnum

common.xsd:

```
<xs:simpleType name="barringScope">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:long">
        <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="3"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

binding.xjb:

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="common.xsd">
      <jxb:bindings node="xsd:simpleType[@name='barringScope']">
          <jxb:typesafeEnumClass>
               <jxb:typesafeEnumMember value="1" name="one"/>
               <jxb:typesafeEnumMember value="2" name="two"/>
               <jxb:typesafeEnumMember value="3" name="three"/>
          </jxb:typesafeEnumClass>
      </jxb:bindings>
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```